# docker compose debug in visual studio fails with connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

I have a docker compose and Docker file, Django and Postgres.
When I run this command from the bash shell (docker-compose up) it works fine.
However when I run it from visual studio debug I get the error about the socket.
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "django"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "emailmapperapp:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "args": [
                    "runserver",
                    "0.0.0.0:8000",
                    "--nothreading",
                    "--noreload"
                ],
                "file": "manage.py"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: email_mapper_admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: email_mapper_password12345
      POSTGRES_DB: email_mapper
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  web:
    image: emailmapperapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Docker compose debug:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  emailmapperapp:
    image: emailmapperapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --nothreading --noreload"]
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 5678:5678
```

Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10-slim

EXPOSE 8000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "email_mapper_app.wsgi"]
```

Any suggestions welcome!